# ant_rules_r3.xml:209 & 395 ERROR

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I'm running mac osx.
I just cant find a answer to this error:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:395: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:209: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 4/10/2497, 17:55 น.

Total time: 22 seconds
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:395: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/ed_crub/Documents/Android SDK/tools/ant/ant_rules_r3.xml:209: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: Debug Certificate expired on 4/10/2497, 17:55 น

i'm try remove ~/.android/debug.keystore and change machine's locale (date and time).It don't work.

Can any one give me an answer to this problem please?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you not using eclipse?

Comment: i'm try run on eclipse, but same error.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you should remove the debug keystore,  I think you just need a valid one. See android development FAQ

[I can't compile my app because the build tools generated an expired debug certificate](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/troubleshooting.html#signingcalendar)